# Create Bitmap from jpeg

Tags: android, android-layout

In android, I'm trying to create a bitmap from a jpeg that I downloaded and copied to a drawable folder under res.

attached is my code:

```
public void draw(Canvas g, Resources res, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    Bitmap im = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.green_dragon);
    Bitmap im = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.green_dragon);
    g.drawBitmap(im, null, new Rect(x*w, y*h, (x*w)+w, (y*h)+h), new Paint());
}
```

Android does not recognize the R.drawable.green_dragon in either the decodeResource or decodeFile lines.  I have also tried both refreshing and cleaning the application.  Neither helped.  When I looked up the image properties the type is File and the path is .jpg.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only resources that are packaged with the application can be referenced using the `R` object.

Anything you download must either be saved to a database or a file. I'm assuming you've already downloaded and saved the file. At which point you either need the a String that has the `Path` of the jpg or a `FileDescriptor` for the jpg.

Once you have either you can load the bitmap using:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( PathToFileString );
```

or

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor( fileDescriptorObject );
```

Comment: All set.  Works when copy image to drawable folder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `srcRect` for `drawBitmap` should not be null but this:

```
Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, im.getWidth(), im.getHeight());
```